# pandas string match in a column containing multiple values separated by a '|'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe which has multiple IDs and values such as below:

## Sample Dataframe:

```
     ID        VALUE
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
2  9991        62003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
```

**I'd like to get only the subset of the dataframe which contains an element from list of strings.

```
l = [2003, 2005, 5411, 1786]
```

In the above example, everything that matches '2003'.**

## Expected Result:

```
     ID        VALUE
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
```

## Current Results:

Using `df[df['VALUE'].str.contains('2003')]` gives everything including '62003' which needs to be excluded.

Using `df[df['VALUE'].str.match('2003')]` gives only:

```
     ID        VALUE
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
```

Here, `3  7440  1428 | 2003` is missing.

**Is there a way to get the expected result for exact match of '2003' but on either side of the '|' or in rows where there is a single value and no pipe.** This result will also need to run through a list of strings to be matched.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex match:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[5401,  '2003 | 5411'],
[5582,  '2003'],
[9991,  '62003'],
[7440,  '1428 | 2003']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'value'])
result = df[df['value'].str.contains(r'\b2003\b', regex=True)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     id        value
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
```

The pattern `'\b2003\b'` matches 2003 surrounded by word boundaries. If you have multiple patterns, you could also use a regex match, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[5401,  '2003 | 5411'],
[5582,  '2003'],
[9991,  '62003'],
[7440,  '1428 | 2003'],
[7440,  '2004 | 2002']]

needles = ['2003', '2004']
pattern = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(needle) for needle in needles])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'value'])
result = df[df['value'].str.contains(pattern, regex=True)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     id        value
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
4  7440  2004 | 2002
```

An alternative approach is to split the string on `|` and check for each value, for example:

```
needles = ['2003', '2004']

def contains(xs, ns=set(needles)):
    return any(x.strip() in ns for x in xs.split('|'))


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'value'])
result = df[df['value'].apply(contains)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     id        value
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
4  7440  2004 | 2002
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. this is a small sample of the dataframe. Actually, there are numerous values I'd like to match from a large dataframe. Is there a way to dynamically create a regex from the values to be matched? // I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you mean like 2004 and 2003 for example?

Comment: Yes, that looks perfect. Let me try :)

Comment: Okay, I've tried it and I'm still stuck at a point where the query ends up returning `NaN` where there is a single element in the column (no '|' ). This causes the single `2003` rows to be excluded as well. :( 
Any idea why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Without further information, I cannot tell, it works for the second example (the ones using multiple patterns). See that it detects the rows `[5582, 2003]` (containing a single 2003)

Comment: @ParvBanks A work around could be to combine both masks using or (`|`) that is the mask in your code (the simple contains) with the mask from the regexes.

Comment: Is there a way we could split using `|` and then check either (stripped) column for the element? Not sure if that's the right approach though.

Comment: @ParvBanks Updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I'm still facing the same issue. So it's nothing to do with the solution, both work fine with a small dataset (using `pd.read_clipboard()`) but I guess there's something wrong when we apply the logic which turns the single values to `NaN`

Comment: I've found the reason, it was because the dataframe was treating single values as `int` and the ones with a `|` as string (odd, I thought the entire column was supposed to be one dtype.
It was fixed after specifying `dtype=str` in the `pd.read_excel` command.

Thanks for your help!~

Answer (score 1):

Just another example itself with `str.contains`, where you can pass multiple values itself using regex pattern `OR (|)`

Initial DataFrame borrowed from @Daniel , Where i'm looking for three distinct  values ie `2003 , 2004 and 2018`

**DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
     id        value
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
2  9991        62003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
4  7440  1428 | 2018
5  7440  2004 | 2002
```

**Result:**

```
>>> df[df['value'].str.contains(r'\b2003|2004|2018\b', case=False, regex=True)]
     id        value
0  5401  2003 | 5411
1  5582         2003
3  7440  1428 | 2003
4  7440  1428 | 2018
5  7440  2004 | 2002
```

Comment: Thanks @pygo. This works well for a smaller set of strings to match. I guess Daniel's solution works better for a much longer list.

Comment: @ParvBanks, Cool, you can upvote the answer if works in a current situation however you can mark the Daniel's answer as accepted.

Comment: Sure, will do. At the moment, I'm still facing issues with some of the values. I'm still stuck at a point where the query ends up returning NaN where there is a single element in the column (no '|' ). This causes the single 2003 rows to be excluded as well. :( Any idea why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the initial  few lines of the code and data that way we can try.